# how to call button on clickListner outside the custom adapter of listview.

Tags: android, listview, button, adapter, onclicklistener

I have a `Button` on `Listview` and a custom adapter that loads the `ListView`. I want to call the `Button` `onClickListner` in main class not in the adapter class. how can i do this.

Comment: Is your button dynamically added or using XMl layout??

Answer (score 0):

You can create one **Global Interface**

Like this

```
package com.radiofrance.interfaces;

public abstract class GlobalInterface implements eventInterface {

    public void onClick(int values) {

    }

    public void onCancel() {
    }

}
```

Then Implement this interface in **Your Activity** from which you call your adapter

```
public class SampleClickListener extends GlobalInterface {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final int values, final boolean state) {

}
}
```

now in your adapter **pass this object of interface**

```
Adapter adt = new Adpater(this, R.layout.row, arrRow,
                    new SampleClickListener());
```

and **from your adapter** call

```
listner.onClick(position, false);
```

Thanks